How to store google form responses into multiple spreadsheets? Error in existing provided solution
This is in context to an existing Answer, I was trying to replicate the solution provided in this answer, although I am facing some error. Here is link to the existing answer:
How to store google form responses into multiple spreadsheets?
Here is the code:
function copyFormResponses(e)
    {
      let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Sheet_URL").getSheetByName("SheetName");
      let range = e.range;
      let values = e.values;
      let lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
      for(let i=1; i<=values.length; i++)
      {
          ss.getRange(lastRow+1,i).setValue(values[i-1]);
      }
    }


Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLastRow')
at copyFormResponses(Test_Transfer:6:20)

Trigger: Made manually on Apps Script. Attached is the trigger config:


Welcome to Stack Overflow. While it's helpful to include links to previous questions and answers, posts should be self-contained, and errors messages should be added as text, not as images. Please add a [mcve].

Please add more info. Include your script. Include the trigger.

The example should include a description of the script, the trigger, the relevant parts of the form and spreadsheets. This is important because scripts can be standalone or bound to spreadsheets, forms, etc. Triggers could be created manually or by using code. Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi, I added the code, error and trigger details.

If you're getting this error it's likely that you have a typo (extra space maybe?) in the sheet name for getSheetByName("Sheet Name") or a typo in the openByUrl("URL-Here") on line 2 of your code if you copied the code directly from the question linked in your post.

I did check but there is no typo in the mentioned code lines.

In that case, posting the code should help quickly identify the issue.
